# C# keypress starting timer

Tags: c#, timer, keypress

I am trying to make a program which does:
If you press start(button1) it should start working
if you press stop(button2) it stops until u press start again

my goal: when it is on, and space is being pressed, it should "spam" spaces (you hold down space, and it keeps jumping in game(cs)) 
Basically I am trying to create bunny hopper for games.
I am pretty new to c# form applications so I don't know whats wrong with my code..

what doesnt work: keydown and up events

here is my code:

```
namespace Bunny
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {            
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        Boolean isOn = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            timer.Interval = 50;                      
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(isOn)
            {
                SendKeys.Send(" ");                    
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;
            timer.Stop();
        }
        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {
                isOn = true;
            }
        }
        private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {
                isOn = false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the program doing?  What behavior are you getting right now?

Comment: it works if I set isOn true manually(at inicialization), but it doesnt work with the space (tried other keys as well)

Comment: where do you use method `bunny_KeyUp` ?

Comment: oh, I guess that shouldnt be bunny but form1, but still doesnt work, this works: protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) but it doesnt detect if the key is still being pressed... This is whole program,

Comment: When you click the button, the button gets the focus.  The SendKeys keys now go to the button, not whatever program is supposed to get them.  You will need to *refocus* the window.  Pinvoke required, GetForegroundWindow and SetForegroundWindow.

Comment: You need a global hotkey for this.

Answer (score 0):

For your keys to be detected in game, it needs to be programmed as a global hotkey. My guess is that your key-presses are being detected when the form is focused, but not in game.

See the link below.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2213/Beginner-s-Tutorial-Using-global-hotkeys